# jQM 1.4 : event handler for buttons in listview

Tags: javascript, listview, jquery-mobile, event-handling

I have a listview containing styled items with buttons : (working example : http://jsfiddle.net/tQ88p/)

```
<ul id="runningJobList" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" class="ui-listview ui-listview-inset ui-corner-all ui-shadow">
    <li data-role="list-divider" role="heading" class="ui-li-divider ui-bar-inherit ui-first-child">Traitements en cours</li>
    <li class="styled-li ui-li-static ui-body-inherit ui-last-child" title="Create a buffer around an input vector file">
        <div class="processStatus">
            <h6>Buffer</h6>
            <p><strong>ACCEPTED: </strong>Process foo accepted</p>
        </div>
        <div class="processButtons">
             <button id="holdProcess-f80a5070-c3e8-11e3-ae6a-005056af4240" data-inline="true" data-icon="lock" data-iconpos="notext"></button>
             <button id="killProcess-f80a5070-c3e8-11e3-ae6a-005056af4240" data-inline="true" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext"></button>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

In my app, the list is built dynamically, but the static jsfiddle example show my problem : the click handler on buttons doesn't work.

I think it's maybe because click event is attempt to be fired only by li on listview. Is it possible to have custom buttons in listview ?
If it is possible, how to declare the event handler on them?

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT**: after Omar answer, I removed div around buttons and click handler worked as expected. But click handler doesn't work when list is built dynamically : http://jsfiddle.net/tQ88p/3/

**SOLUTION**: finally, it doesn't work with buttons, but it works well with anchor. Working example : http://jsfiddle.net/tQ88p/4/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you're wrapping a `button` in a div, while you can use either `<a>` or `<button>` tags without the need to wrap any of them.

```
<a href="#" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all ui-shadow ui-btn-inline ui-icon-lock ui-btn-icon-notext" id=""></a>
```

When you append items dynamically, you need to *delegate* events to those items.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function () {
  $("li").on("click", "a, button", function () {
    /* code */
  });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/wbvXL/)**

Comment: Actually, I didn't wrap my button in a div, but I copied generated HTML and forgot to remove wrapping... Anyway, thank you for your answer, I didn't know how to delegate events like that.